# Shouldn't review bans apply only on the category of the failed audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, late-answers

I've been reviewing posts for I short time, so I understand that there's a lot I need to learn on the *reviewing* topic.

Nevertheless, I put some effort in it, reading wall of texts sometimes related to topics in which I'm not an expert. Just to say I'm not a *robo-reviewer*. I also skip a lot of proposed reviews I'm not sure about.

Now, whilst I'm fine with *Triage* and *First Post* queues (better in the first than in the latter), (it seems  that) I'm really bad in evaluating *Late Answers*. My main fail field is related to answers with links; I visit them, their contents seem to be helpful, and since my personal perspective is that a short helpful answer with link is better than no answer, I sometimes wrongly accept them. **But I'm not going to argue about it**. I accept this community policy.

What I don't understand is why should a reviewer be banned on ALL review categories if they are bad in one of them. If a student fails an exam he has to repeat only the test for that subjects! Isn't it a shame, for the community, to lose his help for all the other categories?

I understand that in case of robo-reviewers it wouldn't be enough. But for people who do their best it is a little to harsh, and doesn't help them to **really** understand what was wrong in their reviews.

So why don't separate categories? Bans don't need to be less strict: for example the system could lower the tolerance for the single category. It would be a harsher-category-based-audit-system. ;)

Comment: Wow! 3 downvotes, at the moment.  Shouldn't downvotes be related to wrongly formatted questions? Is my question incomplete? I'm not going to delete it just to get *peer pressure* badge, because my question is wel formatted and well written. SO community should think about avoiding downvotes on a question just because they *disagree* with assertions contained in it. ;)

Comment: Users can downvote for several reasons. The canonical three are: because they think the question lacks clarity, because they think it doesn't show adequate research, or simply because they think _it is not useful question_. The last one is a particularly broad reason. Also, in meta votes are many times used to express disagreement with the perceived intent of a question. E.g. in this case: let's make review bans less strict.

Comment: Ok, I understand. BTW: in this case you would have failed an audit, since my point was not asking for *less strict bans*. But rather, even *more harsh* bans, but category based. ;)

Comment: Care to elaborate which part of your question argues for _harsher_ review bans? I just don't see it.

Comment: *What I don't understand is why should a reviewer be banned on ALL review categories if is bad in one of them.*

Comment: And how that says a review ban should be harsher in any way? I don't think I follow you. Are you sure that means what you think it means?

Comment: Nowhere here do you mention ANYTHING more harsh about the ban. You limit its scope, but don't increase its depth, its time, its impact. You're making it less affecting to others. That's...... not harsher in any way

Comment: @Patrice are you sure? Read better. ;)

Comment: @Cubo I mean, if you play "I'll edit my question to say something and then make it look like you can't read", I think I'll stop right now, thanks. That whole "stricter" has been added after my comment. It feels a bit disingenuous to get pinged that. Have a good day. Good luck with the reviews

Comment: It was a joke, @Patrice, take it easy.  I really didn't mean to *cheat*. I edited because it could have been explained better, but I'm aware there's no actually way I can recover from a -6. So I think that a joke was the best way to sportly face this s%%tstorm. The was an emoticon! ;) Programmers can also be funny guys, not only serious nerds. Have a nice evening.

Comment: I wouldn't call -6 a s%%tstorm. Go look at MSE sometime

Comment: @Cubo written is a bad medium for emotions and joke. You wrote a ";)" that you wanted to convey a joking tone, I caught it as condescending. That's why we actually suggest not to go for jokes. And btw..... calling people who don't like or get your humor "serious nerds" won't make you any friends... especially on a "no nonsense, high signal, low noise" site like Stack...

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful. The link breaks, and the answer is crap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's unfortunate in your specific case that you've had trouble with one category in particular. But the purpose of review audits is not so much to verify that you're good enough at reviewing each category but more in general to verify that you are paying attention when you review. There are some problematic audits sometimes, but the idea is that you should only fail one if you *are* robo-reviewing. That's why you get banned from all categories if you fail enough of them.

It sounds like you really are paying attention, but failed some audits due to an initial misconception or disagreement about the definition of link-only not-an-answers. It also sounds like you've cleared that up since then, so you shouldn't have any more trouble with it in the future.

For future reference, it may be helpful to read [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), particularly the "Links to an Answer" section. There's a link there to this other post on MSE, [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) that goes into more detail.

Comment: I accepted this answer because, though I don't fully agree with that, because at least you understood the human frustration. Btw, my last fail was about a really a long answer, with something like "In this link you find how to fix this part **link1**; in this other link you find the explanation of this concept **link2**, and finally in this link you find yadayada **link3**".

Comment: I'd have to look at that specific review before I could comment on it, but in general it is possible to occasionally encounter a bad review audit. It _might_ be just an unfortunate coincidence that you got one when you were on the edge of a review ban. This answer talks about what you can do if you think you've found one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work.

Comment: But before you decide on that, if you haven't already, I'd really suggest reading those links I added to the answer to make sure you understand what's expected to be considered not an answer, even if you don't necessarily agree with it.

Answer (score 6):

To use your student analogy, if a student fails an exam their *global* GPA is still impacted.  You could be a stellar student in other categories as evidenced by your exam score, but your overall GPA could be poor.

With that...I personally don't believe that there should be any lenience on this.  The main reason that people get in trouble with these reviews and audits is that they rush through things a bit too fast.  Slowing down - *globally* slowing down - is in the best interests of everyone.

Comment: I understand your point, but your counter-analogy was not very good. :P Anaway  I still believe that my failures were not critical. I always ask myself: can it be helpful? And since answerers cannot copy the whole internet on SO, I (seemingly wrongly) approved answers because there was no reason to copy and paste user manuals in the answers. There was no rush in my (apparently wrong) evaluations.

Comment: What you describe happened to me, so I also dislike your analogy.

Comment: No one should copy and paste user manuals into the answer box, @Cubo78. However, [we have a minimum standard for all posts here](/help/how-to-answer) that they be *self-contained*. If the post consists of nothing more than a link to an off-site resource, then it is not acceptable. Ideally, the post will contain a *summary* of what can be found elsewhere, rather than a copy-paste, but sometimes a quotation of a few sentences can be sufficiently enlightening. In either case, attribution (author's name and link) is required. This standard helps to stave off link rot.

Comment: Furthermore: it seems that answers have to be verbose. And though I think that a simple "Yes." might *sometimes* be better than a huge answer repeating Computer Science theory starting from the meaning of "binary", I've skipped a lot of reviews with short answers.

Answer (score 5):

The most important thing is that the ban gets your attention. If you're only banned from one queue, it'd be possible to miss the fact that you're banned especially for the shorter bans.

Additionally, it makes sense to do a global ban because in many cases the problem that caused an issue in one queue would be applicable to other queues:

- Thought a First Post with serious formatting issues "Looks OK"? You shouldn't be reviewing edits.
- Thought an off-topic question in Triage was OK? That'd be a problem in First Posts too.
- Approved an edit adding in a spam link? Not recognizing spam is an issue in every queue.

In your specific case, I'd think allowing link only answers would be an issue in both Late Answers and First Posts.

Comment: But (the last one) was about a really a long answer, with something like "In this link you find how to fix this part **link1**; in this other link you find the explanation of this concept **link2**, and finally in this link you find yadayada **link3**". Not so simple to detect it. In my ingenuous opinion it could be helpful.

Comment: @Cubo78 A suggestion: imagine all the links are gone from the answer or all point to 404 - is the answer still useful? If not, treat it like a link-only answer.

Comment: Yes. I understand it. Anyway I want to repeat how I din't mean arguing on correctness of audit fails, but just on a single ban for all review categories.

Comment: *Not so simple to detect it.* @Cubo78 Yes, which means you also would have said this answer was OK had it appeared in First Posts instead of Late Answers. It makes sense that the ban would apply in multiple queues.

Answer (score 4):

We want you to take some time to consider why you've failed and not just move on to making the same or a different mess in one queue after another till we need a major rather than a minor clean up of your mistakes.

Sure you might be doing OK in the other queues but you're not the only person with review capability so someone else can cover for you while you reflect on exactly why you're banned.